# Is lexicographic ordering totally ordered?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to proof if a lexicographic ordering is totally ordered by not using Cartesian Product. Which is what I originally used, but my Professor marked it wrong and said that I can't use two sets to prove it. I know that it is totally ordered, I just don't know how else to prove this question.

**My original assumption**
Assume (A1, ⪯1) and (A2, ⪯2) are ordered sets. Let ⪯1 be the lexicographic order on A1 x A2. Then ⪯1 is a total ordering on A1 x A2 iff both ⪯1 and ⪯2 are total orderings.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Marked it wrong without proving an answer ?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are trying to prove? Definitions would be helpful. Your description of the grader’s objection is unclear. What you are trying to prove is correct, but is that what the actual question said, or just your interpretation of the question?

Comment: I didn't include my proof in this question. Just my assumption.

Comment: @Thomas the question given to the class was just "Is lexicographic ordering totally ordered?" I'm trying to prove that a lexicographic ordering is a total order. The professor said I cannot use two sets to prove the question.

Comment: Again, that sounds like you misunderstood the professor’s complaint. But how is lexicographer order defined in your class?

Comment: For example, lexicographic order used on words in a dictionary has up to $n$ letters, not just $2$-letter words.

Comment: @Thomas, the definition is "Suppose we have some alphabet of symbols that is partially ordered by some relation. By word, in this context, we mean any string of letters from this alphabet, not necessarily real words. For "words" a = a, az... an and b = b, bz... bm, define a ⪯ b if

1) a and b are identical, or
2) ai ⪯ bi in the alphabet at the first position i where words differ
3) n < m and ai = bi for i = 1, ... , n."

Comment: Okay, then, with that definition, you’ve only proven the lexicographic order is total on two-letter words.

Comment: @Thomas, well how can I prove it for all letter words?

Comment: Please add the definitions , name of text books , course to the question, so everything is in one place , instead of having to browse the comments to find details . Think you were trying to answer this for someone else , wouldn't you want as much as details as possible ? Please help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lexicographic_Order_on_Pair_of_Totally_Ordered_Sets_is_Total_Ordering
this link might help.
also, you should change your lexicographic order from $\preceq_1$ to $\preceq_3$